# with cte union all select

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, union-all

I have two tables **Arrears** and **Invoices** .
I am trying to do the following:

```
;with Acc.. as ( select ....from ....)

select ..... from  Arrears 

UNION ALL

select ... from Invoices
```

the problem is that results are like :

| A header | B header |
| --- | --- |
| row | row |
| row | row |

the output should be like this:

| Table | B header | c header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arrays | row | row |
| Invoices | row | row |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a string literal to each query to indicate what table it came from:

```sql
SELECT 'Arrays' AS table_name, *
FROM   arrays
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Invoices' AS table_name, *
FROM   invoices
```